# C++ Checking while condition with user input array

Tags: c++

I'm student in high school and I wanna to make simple game with guessing random number and I had problem with user inputed array while I need to check the condition.
When it comes to checking condition it says there wasn't declared i.
Below I leave code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int PlayerAns[200];

    int iNumSecret, iNumGuess;

    int iWrongAns = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));
    int iNumMax = 100;

    iNumSecret = rand() % iNumMax + 1;
    cout << "========== Simple Game =========== "
         << "\n";

    do
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            cout << "Guess the number od 1 do " << iNumMax << "\n";

            cin >> PlayerAns[i];

            if (iNumSecret < PlayerAns[i] && PlayerAns[i] >= 0 && PlayerAns[i] <= 100)
            {
                cout << "  - Secret number is lower ! "
                     << "\n";
            }
            else if (iNumSecret > PlayerAns[i] && PlayerAns[i] >= 0 && PlayerAns[i] <= 100)
            {
                cout << "  - Secret number is higher ! "
                     << "\n";
            }
            else if (PlayerAns[i] < 0 || PlayerAns[i] > 100)
            {
                cout << "  - Number is out of scope ! "
                     << "\n";
                iWrongAns++;
            }
        }

    }

    while (iNumSecret != PlayerAns[i]);

    {
        cout << "--- You get it !!!"
             << "\n";

        cout << PlayerAns << "\n";

        cout << "You guess number out of scope that many times: " << iWrongAns << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the `i` being used in the `do-while` condition `(iNumSecret != PlayerAns[i])` coming from ?

Comment: From for loop under 'do' when I'm inputing numbers into array

Comment: The only `i` in this code is declared local to the for-loop (in the decl+init portion of the for-loop specifically). There is no `i` identifier outside of that loop. Refer to you language reference text about variable *scope*

Comment: If I declare i earlier while checking condition dosen't  work

Answer (score 1):

The variable `i` is defined only inside the for loop in that case.

If you wanted to, you can define `i` before the do while loop, and then use it in the for loop like so:

```
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
...
}
```

Suggestion:
You can try not using the for loop and make the `PlayerAns` an integer instead of an array.

Comment: If I declare i earlier while checking condition dosen't work.
And I don't want to declare this as integer beacouse i need all "player" answers to cout  them later